# An Issue With Italian Kingdom Hearts 3

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

A couple months ago, I had ordered KH3 online and got it delivered. Due to me having not gotten past re:Chain of Memories at the time, I didn't pay much attention to it until just recently when I finished Chi Back Cover. As it turns out, the copy of KH3 I have is in Italian. My question is aimed more towards people familiar with how GameStop works: would I be able to trade in my unopened Italian copy of KH3 for an English version, or would I have to go though somewhere else? Alternatively, would there be a language setting to put the game in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soneone who lives in a country where games come in 3 languages (FR,DE,IT), I'm always reluctant buying games in a store because the packaging rarely mentions English as supported language, but since my system is in English, the games always play in English.

You didn't mention what console you're playing on but the game's language is using whatever language your console is set to. Try to set the console's language to English and relaunch KH3 and it should be in English.

To change the language on PS4, do the following:

- Go to Settings from the PS4 main menu
- Scroll down and click Language
- Click System Language
- Pick the language and accept it

To change the language on [Xbox One](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/system/dashboard-or-hub-in-another-language), do the following:

- Press the Guide button on your controller.
- Go to Settings, and then select System Settings.
- Select Console Settings.
- Select Language and Locale.
- Select Language.
- Select the language that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know this actually! It's a huge relief to know that it works that way; means a whole lot less stress for me!